# Get json data from Bing Search API in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, bing-api, bing-search

I'm trying to get the json data returned using the Bing Search API and displaying it.
The json result returned is of the form:

```
{"d":{"results":[{"__metadata":{"uri":"https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/News?Query=\u0027britain\u0027&$skip=0&$top=1","type":"NewsResult"},"ID":"38eda3ba-9e50-4d48-9fd1-bde42b743966","Title":"Britain\u0027s Prince William and Kate try archery in Bhutan","Url":"http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/world/south-asia/Britains-Prince-William-and-Kate-try-archery-in-Bhutan/articleshow/51835828.cms","Source":"Times of India","Description":"Britain\u0027s Catherine looks on as she watches Prince William prepare to fire an arrow at an archery ground in Th... Read More THIMPHU: Britain\u0027s Prince William and his wife Kate tried their hand at Bhutan\u0027s national sport of archery on Thursday as they began ...","Date":"2016-04-15T08:30:00Z"}],"__next":"https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/News?Query=\u0027britain\u0027&$skip=15"}}
```

What I have tried to do is this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script src="jquery-1.12.3.js">

$(document).ready(function() {

  var appId = ':MyKeyHere';

  function getNews() {
    var azureKey = btoa(appId);
    var myUrl = 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/v1/News?Query=%27britain%27&$format=json';

    $.ajax({
      method: 'post',
      url: myUrl,
      dataType:"json"

      //Set headers to authorize search with Bing
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + azureKey
      },
      success: function(data) {
       var json = data.d.results[0].Title;    
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = json;
      },
      failure: function(err) {
        console.error(err);  
      }
    });
  };

  getNews();

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?
I'm new to this. So, a few questions:

1. Does the data variable contain the json object, or does it contain the json string and I need to parse it?
2. I am getting no output and no errors either. What am I missing?

Comment: If you look at the [`$.ajax` docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), you'll see that the error callback key is `error`, not `failure`. So you might be getting an error and just not know :) Also, `data` will be the JSON object - jQuery handles the parsing for you when you tell it the `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: Though you should note that the above code will almost certainly not work because of the [Same-Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), which says that you can't (trivially) make cross-domain requests. To get around this, see if they have a `jsonp` API endpoint. Otherwise, you'll likely have to make the request on your server (and either way your API key should not be in the JS where it's public!)

Comment: I changed it to error and tried. If I get an error where will it be displayed? In the console? @MatthewHerbst

Comment: Yes, in the console. Try using this as your error function: `error: function(jqXHR, error, textStatus) { console.error(jqXHR, error, textStatus); }` That should give you all the error information available.

Comment: Nothing, no error. @MatthewHerbst

Comment: What do you mean by ' make the request on your server '? @MatthewHerbst

Comment: @MatthewHerbst — JSONP is a nasty hack. CORS has been around for many years now and is a much saner solution to the problem. I'd hope that if Bing wanted client side access then they would offer CORS (which would just work transparently) and not JSONP. (And the platform [does supports CORS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-cors-consume-javascript/))

Comment: @grindel — He means that the request to bing should come from your web server and not your visitors' browsers.

Comment: Worrying about cross origin issues at this point is premature anyway. Open your browser's developer tools. Look in the console. See if you get a cross-origin related error message before you start considering it a problem.

Comment: @Quentin I agree, though I think more people offer jsonp just because it's a lot simpler to implement. @ Grindel what browser are you using?

Comment: I don't see any error. But then since it doesn't work, something must be wrong. @Quentin

Comment: Google Chrome @MatthewHerbst

Comment: Have you tried `console.log`ing `data` inside your `success` function? It's entirely possibly that it works fine except you're accessing an empty value.

Comment: I tried. Nothing turns up in the console. But then, when i try console.log("df") then 'df' should be displayed in the console right? No 'df' either. @Quentin

Comment: Seems like you might need to ask a different question first about why your console isn't working properly. In the meantime, try your code on a different browser and see if you get better results